# Is it good idea to make std::regex static?

Tags: c++, regex, static

I use `std::regex` created from string literal like this:

```
std::regex vowel_re("a|e|i|o|u");
```

Is it good idea to make it `static` to save construction time or even `static const`? This regex is most likely will be reused.

Comment: Will the `vowel_re` object be reused? Then yes it might make sense to make it `static` or even `static const`.

Comment: Even if it won't be reused, there is no reason to allocate it dynamically. Make it `static`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the construction time of a block-scope variable is an issue, it is a quick-n-dirty solution to make it `static` or `static const`. Thus the variable gets initialised only once, saving construction time.

However, this does not come for free. The compiler has to generate protection against multithreaded access (so the variable is not initialized twice if the function is called "for the first time" simultaneously by two different threads).

To workaround this new problem, you can define your variable as a global in an anonymous namespace right before your function. Thus it is initialized at startup time (before main is called). You still have to pay attention to *initialization order fiasco*, if you use the function somewhere in the initialization of other globals.

Of course, the best solution is to use something that does not have to be initialized at all during runtime. Unfortunately, the std::regex constructor is not `constexpr`. But you can use boost.spirit as an alternative to std::regex, which can solve your problem and does as much as possible during compile-time.

**EDIT:**

For this very special case, I suspect you could also just use the `find_first_of("aeiou")` method of `std::basic_string` (or the algorithm `std::find_first_of` if you are searching on an arbitrary character range). Keep it simple!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I contribute to huge widely-used project and can't introduce boost as dependency ☹.

Comment: I don't think a single if check that always follows the same branch will be significant compared to the overhead of executing a runtime compiled regular expression.